# JS Promise not able to return a result

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm doing my best to get my JS promise working but it's unable to return any results.

```
geocodeAddress = function(streetAddress){

    var geocodeObject = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      // async call to Google's Geocoder - takes street address
      // and returns GPS coordinates

      var gpsPosition = {};
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      if (geocoder) {
        // console.log("This is the street address");
        // console.log(streetAddress);
        geocoder.geocode({'address': streetAddress}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
              console.log("got GPS coordinates for the streetAddress!");
              gpsPosition.B = results[0].geometry.location['B'];
              gpsPosition.k = results[0].geometry.location['k'];
              console.log(gpsPosition);
              resolve(gpsPosition);
            } else {
              alert("No results found");
              reject(Error("It broke"));
            }
          } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            reject(Error("It broke"));
          }
        });
      }

    });

    geocodeObject.then(function(result) {
      console.log("This is the gpsPosition");
      console.log(result); // this console logs the result just fine
      return result;       // however the result can't be returned
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
    });

}
```

If I do `geocodeAddress("1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043")` the function is able to console.log the result, but is unable to then return it on the very next line.

I've been using these as references for promises:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-javascript-promises

http://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-promises/

But the problem with these tutorials (at least the second one) is that they never explicitly return the result. They either console log it (which works) or use it immediately inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any type of async call, you need to handle the result with a callback function instead of looking for the async function to return a value. The reason goes to the very nature of an async op... the thread needs to be able to move onto the next task and handle the result of the async op with a callback function when it has finished. The only way an async op could return the result of the async operation is if the computer held onto the async thread until it was finished, which would make it a sync op. See if this helps:

```
function geocodeAddress(streetAddress) {

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      // async call to Google's Geocoder - takes street address
      // and returns GPS coordinates

      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({'address': streetAddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (results[0]) {
            resolve({B: results[0].geometry.location['B'],
                     k: results[0].geometry.location['k']});
          } else {
            reject(Error("It broke"));
          }
        } else {
          reject(Error("It broke"));
        }
      });
    })
    .then(
      // this is the Promise resolve handler
      function(result) {
        handleGeocodeResult(result);
      },
      // this is the Promise reject handler
      function(err) {
        console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
      });
}

function handleGeocodeResult(result) {
  // for illustration only... this function should actually
  // *BE* the Promise resolve handler.
  console.log("This is the gpsPosition");
  console.log(result); // this console logs the result just fine
}

geocodeAddress("1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043");
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1w2vxbev/)**

Comment: I see. So the Promise Resolve Handler ( `handleGeocodeResult`) that is called in `.then` and passed the `result` as a parameter can't actually return a hard value. It can, though, do another operation inside the handler itself, such as store the result into a variable:

`function handleGeocodeResult(result) {
  // for illustration only... this function should actually
  // *BE* the Promise resolve handler.
  console.log("This is the gpsPosition");
  console.log(result); // this console logs the result just fine
  myResult = result; // this works
  return result; // does NOT work
};`

Comment: BTW, is there any way on Stack to format comments to questions so that everything isn't all on one line?

Comment: More or less, yes. There's nothing preventing the function from returning a value, it's just a question of scope. In other words, what would the async handler be returning a value to? Everything you need to know about comment formatting is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting): spoiler - no line breaks :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are using `geocodeAddress` function. You are expecting a promise to return on the very next line. What you should really be doing is return the promise from `geocodeAddress`, and use it as a promise.

```
geocodeAddress = function(streetAddress){

  // sorry i omitted the resolve here, for clarity, here more explicit:
  var geocodeObject = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve('hello world');
  });

  // return the promise
  return geocodeObject.then(function() {});
};

// use the geocodeAddress as a promise
var geoAddressPromise = geocodeAddress('alasjdf');

// see geoAddressPromise is a promise object, you can't console log the result.
// you can call 'then' method on it.

geoAddressPromise.then(function(result) {
   // put your code here instead of the next line.
   // you can console.log the result here
   console.log(result);

   // this result is the value you pass to 'resolve' callback inside the promise.
   // in this example it s "hello world".
});
```

Comment: Guh, I'm officially lost. Where does `resolve` go then?

Comment: resolve is used when you create a `new Promise`, it's called inside the `new Promise` when you are done with async operation and want to return/resolve the promise. please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but I will not accept the answer because your answer is extremely unclear and would not actually help someone trying to learn how to return a value from a promise.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny What is it that you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Please give an actual working example of a promise that `returns` a value which can then be stored inside a variable for later use. As you can see in my OP, I am able to console log the value, but unable to return the value in the very next line. I have been unable to find any documentation that matches the workflow you have described.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny, A promise returns a promise object, it doesn't return a value that you can console.log. If you want to console.log the value, you have to use the promise objects `then` method to get the result. I refactored my answer to reflect that.